# mysql ajax table editor doesnt find primarycolvalue

Tags: javascript

I was using the previous version of mysqlAjaxTableEditor but I had to upgrade to the new one, so I downloaded the new mysqlAjaxTableEditor but there is a bug in it. I need the value of the first column in a javascript function when i click on a row, but the value isn't passed.

Does anyone know what I should do to make it work? Or do you have an alternative solution?

This is the relevant part of the code in the initiateEditor function

```
$tableName = 'tblKlant';
$primaryCol = 'idtblKlant';
$errorFun = array(&$this,'logError');
$permissions = $rights;

$this->Editor = new AjaxTableEditor($tableName,$primaryCol,$errorFun,$permissions,$tableColumns);
$this->Editor->setConfig('tableInfo','cellpadding="1" width="1200" class="mateTable"');
$this->Editor->setConfig('tableTitle','Klanten');
$this->Editor->setConfig('addRowTitle','Klant toevoegen');
$this->Editor->setConfig('editRowTitle','Klant bewerken');
$this->Editor->setConfig('paginationLinks',true);
$this->Editor->setConfig('instanceName',$this->mateInstances[0]);
$this->Editor->setConfig('displayNum','10');
$this->Editor->setConfig('extraRowInfo','ondblclick="bekijkme(\'#primaryColValue#\',\'#rowNum#\');" style="cursor: pointer;"');
```

This is the javascript function

```
function bekijkme(id, rownum)
{
    alert(rownum);
    alert("id "+id);
    window.open("retour.php?klantid="+id,"inner");
}
```

So the first alert works, but the second one just returns "id" without number.